# Which static class initializes first?

Tags: c#, .net, initialization, static-classes

Which static class initializes first if we have one more static classes in our project?

For example: Below code gives null exception.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            First.Write();
            Second.Write();
        }
    }
    static class First
    {
        public static int[] firstArray = new int[20];
        public static int[] secondArray = Second.secondArray;
        public static void Write()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(firstArray.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(secondArray.ToString());
        }
    }
    static class Second
    {
        public static int[] firstArray = First.firstArray;
        public static int[] secondArray = new int[30];
        public static void Write()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(firstArray.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(secondArray.ToString());
        }
    }
```

If you pay attention, you will see that if `First` class will initialize itself so `secondArray` field of `Second` would be null. But if `Second` class would initialize first so `Second` class `firstArray` would be null. I am trying to tell that which initialize first makes different results.

I think that it is abstract question about my project. I encounter it while trying to understand why I am getting unexpected results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`First` will begin to initialize, assign `firstArray`, then notice that it requires `Second` to be initialized in order to get the initial value of `secondArray`.

`Second` will start initializing, and then notice that it requires First to be initialized. However, the CLR will then notice that First is *already* initializing in the current thread, so it won't block. `Second`'s initialization will complete, and then First's initialization will complete.

Fortunately, the field that `Second` needs has already been assigned, so the "right thing" happens.

That's all very well if `First` *actually* starts initializing first. However, as neither of the classes has a static constructor, it's possible that `Second` will start to initialize first... it would then start to initialize `First`, which would spot that `Second` is already initializing and take `Second.secondArray`'s current value (null) for `First.secondArray`. This would be a Bad Thing. Note that the initialization timing for types without static constructors has [changed in .NET 4](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0/) - not in a spec-breaking way, but possibly in an existing-code-breaking way.

If both `First` and `Second` had static constructors, then `First` would be initialized first, as that's the first class that `Main` touches.

Moral of the answer: don't do this. Type initializers which refer to each other are very error prone. For another example, see Eric Lippert and Neal Gafter's NDC 2010 talk, "C# Puzzlers" which can be viewed on the [NDC video page](http://streaming.ndc2010.no).

Comment: Does the standard guarantee this order? My guess was that each class initialises at some undefined before the first access, which turns this into a dependency cycle that gets resolved randomly.

Comment: @Tim: I've updated my answer - with no static constructors, the order is indeed undefined.

Comment: With debugger attached to VS2005, a Bad Thing happens - `Second.firstArray` gets set to `null`

Comment: And here I thought some of those puzzlers was purely academic :P

Comment: @Jon Skeet: After few test i see that changing write method ordering doesn't change result.First class constructor work first and again throw null exception.

Comment: @Freshblood: Do you mean changing the ordering to the *calls* to Write, or the ordering *within* the Write methods? The ordering of the calls in Main *will* make a difference if both types have static constructors.

Comment: Second.Write();First.Write(); It doesn't change static constructor initialize ordering  If both has static contructors with different call ordering.

Comment: Sorry for my poor english if i still couln't explain what i am trying to say.I mean call ordering of methods is not dependant for static method initializers.

Comment: Whose on first? I don't know! Third base! (I had to do it) sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any guarantee as to which static type is initialised first.  To ensure fields are initialised properly this way, you'd need to add a static constructor, e.g.:

```
static class Second
{
    public static int[] firstArray = First.firstArray;
    public static int[] secondArray = new int[30];

    static Second() { }

    public static void Write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(firstArray.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(secondArray.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now, when you run the same thing again, it works...